# "Tap-And-Hold" Gesture on ScatterViewItem with Surface Toolkit for Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, gesture-recognition, surface-toolkit

I can't find out the best way to implement this gesture on ScatterViewItems. Also, I would like to use a wipe-gesture but that's further away ...

Answer (score 0):

There are some support for Gestures in the [Blake.NUI](http://blakenui.codeplex.com/) project. There's currently only support for Tap and Double tap (see the [gesture page](http://blakenui.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Gestures)) but more could be added. In fact, I'm also in need of a Hold gesture but I haven't finished it yet.